# Vue.js : How to call a method of page from layout event?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, vue-component

In my design, page layout has  sidebar and page shows image gallery
In initial load page loads all images without filter
When click  button in sidebar, page should show filtered images.
I can get filtered response from API server in click event of sidebar, but cant call image load function of page
How can I call loading function of page in sidebar's click event? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an event bus.

Create a js file (could be `EventBusLayout.js`) with the following code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export let EventBusLayout = new Vue();
```

Then in your layout/sidebar component:

```html
<script>

import { EventBusLayout } from './EventBusLayout.js';

export default {

  methods: {
    sidebarClick() {
       EventBusLayout.$emit('sidebarclick');
    }
  }

}

</script>
```

And in your page component:

```html
<script>

import { EventBusLayout } from './EventBusLayout.js';

export default {

  beforeMount() {
    EventBusLayout.$on('sidebarclick',this.myCallbackFunction);
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    EventBusLayout.$off('sidebarclick',this.myCallbackFunction);
  }

  methods: {
    myCallbackFunction() {
       /* do here your stuffs */
    }
  }

}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I'll try it

Comment: @AliDavid glad it helped you. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer